# Menu Dropdownlist ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, bootstrap-3

estou precisando alterar o menu para aplicar um Dropdownlist, porem estou com dificuldade. Estou seguindo os passos do site do bootstrap, mas quando clica não aparece o submenu, segue o código abaixo:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="../../Home/Index"><img src="~/Images/logo_Web.png" width="50" height="50" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            @if (Session["PerfilUsuario"] != null)
            {
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Chamados <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Novo Chamado", "Create", "Chamado")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Acompanhar Chamados", "Index", "Chamado")</li>
                            @if (Session["PerfilUsuario"].ToString().Equals("1") || Session["PerfilUsuario"].ToString().Equals("3")|| Session["PerfilUsuario"].ToString().Equals("5")|| Session["PerfilUsuario"].ToString().Equals("6")){
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Chamados Encerrados", "ChamadosEncerrados", "Chamado")</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    @if (Session["PerfilUsuario"].ToString().Equals("1"))
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Obras", "Index", "Obra")</li>
                    }
                    @if (Session["PerfilUsuario"].ToString().Equals("1") || Session["PerfilUsuario"].ToString().Equals("6"))
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Setores", "Index", "Setor")</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            }
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Chamados BRA</p>
    </footer>
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema, resolvi com a atualização do jquery, atualizei para 1.9.0 ou qualquer versão acima dessa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após colocar o script abaixo o menu funcionou.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Procure marcar uma resposta como aceita para benefício da comunidade. [Veja o Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour): é rápido e esclarece bastante.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe problemas com o seu código. provavelmente deve as condições em seus `if's` não estão sendo preenchidas. 
Retire essas verificações, e teste seu menu sem elas.

Testes seu código assim:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="../../Home/Index"><img src="~/Images/logo_Web.png" width="50" height="50" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Chamados <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Novo Chamado", "Create", "Chamado")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Acompanhar Chamados", "Index", "Chamado")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Chamados Encerrados", "ChamadosEncerrados", "Chamado")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Obras", "Index", "Obra")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Setores", "Index", "Setor")</li>
                </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Chamados BRA</p>
    </footer>
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Caso ainda não funcione, verifique no **console** de seu **navegador** (F12) se está com algum erro.

[Olhe o resultado de seu menu aqui.](https://jsfiddle.net/randrade/v8jx07he/embedded/result/)

Comment: Obrigado @Randrade mas descobri o que estava faltando, foi um script, vou postar como resposta.